# TestCafé: Verify that all the categories are displayed and the Total score

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I just have started learned TestCafé. I have a webpage, and I want to do a test for it using TestCafé to:

- Verify that all the categories and their quotes are displayed, no extra quotes, no missing ones.
- Verify that the "Total score:" is the sum of all quote scores.

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>QA Engineer</title>
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>The Best QA Engineer Ever</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <strong>Awesome Quotes</strong>
        <ul>
          <li><span>Excellent time to become a missing person.</span> (<span class="score">63</span>)</li>
          <li><span>Beware of low-flying butterflies.</span> (<span class="score">36</span>)</li>
          <li><span>I love deadlines. I love the whooshing sound they make as they fly by.</span> (<span class="score">89</span>)</li>
          <li><span>Nothing so needs reforming as other people&#39;s habits.</span> (<span class="score">93</span>)</li>
          <li><span>Do something unusual today.  Pay a bill.</span> (<span class="score">91</span>)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>Famous Quotes</strong>
        <ul>
          <li><span>If your life was a horse, you&#39;d have to shoot it.</span> (<span class="score">83</span>)</li>
          <li><span>You have taken yourself too seriously.</span> (<span class="score">37</span>)</li>
          <li><span>You have the capacity to learn from mistakes.  You&#39;ll learn a lot today.</span> (<span class="score">83</span>)</li>
          <li><span>A classic is something that everyone wants to have read and nobody wants to read.</span> (<span class="score">89</span>)</li>
          <li><span>Yes there is a lot of people doing a great job out there.</span> (<span class="score">44</span>)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    Total score: 708
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Login`.page('http://localhost:8080');

 const scoresSelector = Selector('.score');

 test('test', async t => { 
   let calculatedTotal      = 0;
   let currentScore         = 0;
   let currentScoreSelector = null;
   const scoreElementCount  = await scoresSelector.count;   
   
   for(let i = 0; i < scoreElementCount; i++) {
       currentScoreSelector = scoresSelector.nth(i);
       currentScore         = parseInt(await currentScoreSelector.textContent);
       
       calculatedTotal += currentScore;
   }
   
   const expectedTotal = await ClientFunction(() => {
       debugger;
       var text = document.body.lastChild.nodeValue;
       var value = text.substring(text.indexOf(':') + 1);
      
       return parseInt(value);
   })();
   
   await t.expect(calculatedTotal).eql(expectedTotal);
});
```

See also: [ClientFunction](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/clientfunction/)